# Is bouncy castle safe to use in c# project?

Tags: aes, aes-gcm

I was using AesManaged class in my C# project with .NET framework 4.8.
Now this class is obsolete and I want to use AES with GCM mode.
After research I found 2 way to achieve this:

1. To use Bouncy Castle
2. to use P/Invoke to manually call BCryptEncrypt.

I just want to ensure that Bouncy Castle is safe to use since it is open source.

I have tried Bouncy Castle and it is working fine.